# Log file is not created for console application if it is called through Process in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I have two applications: one WPF and one console application.

On both applications I installed log4net libraries (same version) but with separate `logging.config` files for each application, and they are initialized like:

for WPF (App.xaml.cs):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
   var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, new FileInfo("logging.config"));

   base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

`logging.config` stores log file as `wpf_debug.log`.

for Console:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, new FileInfo("logging.config"));
}
```

`logging.config` stores log file as `console_debug.log`.

Ok then, if I run from WPF application a process

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "PathToConsoleExe";
...
using (Process pr = new Process())
{
   pr.StartInfo = startInfo;

   pr.Start();
   pr.WaitForExit();
}
```

The problem is that I don't see any `.log` file for console application. I don't know why. Only for WPF, the logs are created fine.

If I run console app through command prompt, it works fine.

Comment: My guess is that it tries to load the `loggigng.config` file from the wrong folder. Try setting the `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` property before starting the process

Comment: Yes, it works, that is the solution. Please post it as answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it tries to load the `logging.config` file from the wrong folder. Try setting the `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` property before starting the process